# error: inputDataNilOrZeroLength in Swift with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength)

What does it mean?

```
struct URLService {

    static var language = LocalizationService.shared.language.userSymbol.uppercased()
    static let baseUrl = "http://192.168.9.42:5080"
    
    static func checkLogin(login: String, password: String) {
        let parametrs: Parameters = [
            "language": "RU",
            "password": "password",
            "username": "login"
        ]
        let url = "\(URLService.baseUrl)/someURL"
        let authRequest = AF.request(url,
                                     method: .post,
                                     parameters: parametrs,
                                     encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString))
        authRequest.responseData { (response) in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                print("\(response) check response")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("\(error) check error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

U will help me, if show me other cases with this error and your repairing.

Comment: `print(response.data)`. It's either nil or empty. Is your server supposed to return some value?

Comment: yep
I have to get userId
i try to do request for login view

Comment: Are you sure about `URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)`? Don't you want to put the parameters in the body instead?

Comment: I'm slowpoke =(
If i need to put it into body, i don't need to use URLEncoding? It's will be default case?

Comment: Well. `URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)`, so you are telling that the destination for the parameters are to be put in the query, ie the URL. If you write instead `URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)` it will go in the body... But, do you want URLEncoding or more used JSON? Like `JSONEncoding.default` (since it's a post, it will go in the body)

Comment: God bless you
How can i up your reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me was right:

```
let authRequest = AF.request(url,
                                     method: .post,
                                     parameters: parameters,
                                     encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            authRequest.responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    print("succes")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error while querying database: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
            }
```

JSONEncoding + responseString(Just for more convenience)